# Sometimes my new data replaces old data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, overlapping

this is my first time asking in stackoverflow :)
I have a mid-size winforms application developed in C# that connects to SQL Server 2008, this application is intended to be a business management app (for middle companies), you can make quotations, invoices, and so on.

The point is that sometimes (not always) one user in one computer creates a Quote, that Quote get stored in SQL, and receives an ID as the result.
Then, at the same time another user in another different computer creates another Quote, and, receives the same ID and as a result this last Quote overlaps the first one.

This doesn't happens very often, but it happens, and I can't find why, perhaps the best way is to ensure the individualization of the data, and some of you guys can bring me some light.

The facts are:
It always happen with the two exact persons (we have 6 sales persons and this problem always happens with the same 2 salesperson)
One of those sales person is working on my app remotely using Remote Desktop so, the instance of that app is running in the server
The other sales person is using the app locally on his own computer in the same network where the server is installed.

The process for storing data are as follows:

In the database structure you will find 3 tables as follow:
1) The "data header" of the Quote
2) The "detail" of the Quote
3) The table detail of the Quote that is associated for reporting issues

1) After created the Quote and pressed the button "Accept" the app takes the "Data Header" and stores it, as a result, it gives back an ID (not the ID of the database but an ID originated with some company policy)
2) With the id back, the app starts to store the "detail" in the second table
3) If the user wants to print the Quote, a report is created and for that purpose I "copy" temporarily the detail data from the detail table to the report table

When the error happens, I query the database and I found only one Quote (the last one) is registered, so, I understand that the last quote overlaps the first one.

At first sight the problem could it be related to the way I generate the ID that will be returned by SQL, the way I create is actually quite simple:
- I check the last number assigned to create Quote's ID and register plus one
- If no number exists (first data in the table) I just assign one as the initial ID

Why not take the table key as the ID? because the system needs to comunicate with another system and they need specifical ID's from a range of ID's

The code from the Stored Procedure where creates the ID is the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @newNumDoc INT
SET @newNumDoc = (ISNULL((SELECT MAX(NUMDOC) FROM REMISION_DBF WHERE idEmpresa = @idEmpresa),0) + 1)
IF @newNumDoc IS NULL
    SET @newNumDoc = 1
COMMIT TRAN
```

So, can anyone help me to understand where the problem is or at least to change the focus to ensure no overlapped data will be missed?

Comment: If you use an IDENTITY column, this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you're handling your transaction, and indeed the code that should be within it. Your transaction currently covers the following SQL:

- Get the highest NUMDOC value from your database table
- If it's null, set it to 1.

**But**, this isn't really transaction-worthy, because at no point do you insert another record. There's no reason why another process couldn't then come along and get exactly the same number - and, indeed, this is what you are seeing.

What you need to do is more along the lines of the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @newNumDoc INT
SET @newNumDoc = (ISNULL((SELECT MAX(NUMDOC) FROM REMISION_DBF WHERE idEmpresa = @idEmpresa),0) + 1)
IF @newNumDoc IS NULL SET @newNumDoc = 1
INSERT INTO REMISION_DBF (NUMDOC) VALUES (@newNumbDoc)
COMMIT TRAN
```

This would ensure that your `NUMDOC` is reserved for the current process, and then when it comes to writing your data you simply switch your current `INSERT` for an `UPDATE`.

(This may obviously raise other issues with your system that need resolving separately, but it will give you a starting point that also ensures uniqueness of `NUMDOC` values.

Of course, there are alternatives; for example, one possibility is to use a separate table of "reservations" to avoid pollution of `REMISION_DBF`. But even then, the same `BEGIN TRAN` ... `GET` ... `INSERT` ... `COMMIT` model applies.)